# Java, XML and Android Studio Version

Tags: java, android

how can I know which version of java and XML I am using in my Android Studio, and the version of my Android Studio?

Comment: There is no Android Studio version, once your app is running on a physical device. So... what is this all about?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java version open android studio, go to project structure and it will show you the jdk version you are using. Alternatively, you can type Java on windows search and click on about java.

Android studio version: open android studio go to help and click on about. Alternatively the version you be on the top of the window when you open a project in android studio.